# Python : Inserting multiple values into a table from excel

Tags: python, sql-server-2008-r2, xlrd, pymssql

I have to read data from Excel and insert it into Table...

For this I am using Python 2.7, pymssql and xlrd modules...

My sql connection is working fine and I am also able to read data from Excel properly.

My table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE MONTHLY_BUDGET
(
    SEQUENCE            INT IDENTITY,
    TRANSACTION_DATE    VARCHAR(100),
    TRANSACTION_REMARKS VARCHAR(1000),
    WITHDRAWL_AMOUNT    VARCHAR(100),
    DEPOSIT_AMOUNT      VARCHAR(100),
    BALANCE_AMOUNT      VARCHAR(100)
)
```

My excel values are like this :

```
02/01/2015  To RD Ac no 147825000874    7,000.00    -   36,575.74
```

I am having problem while inserting multiple values in the table... I am not sure how to do this...

```
import xlrd
import pymssql

file_location = 'C:/Users/praveen/Downloads/OpTransactionHistory03-01-2015.xls'

#Connecting SQL Server
conn = pymssql.connect (host='host',user='user',password='pwd',database='Practice')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Open Workbook
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)

# Open Worksheet
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

for rows in range(13,sheet.nrows):
    for cols in range(sheet.ncols):
        cur.execute(
        " INSERT INTO MONTHLY_BUDGET VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", <--- Not sure!!!
        [(sheet.cell_value(rows,cols))])

conn.commit()
```

Error :
     ValueError: 'params' arg () can be only a tuple or a dictionary.

The docs are here : http://pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting says that the "'params' arg() can be only a tuple or a dictionary" but you're passing in a list. Also, your parameter list appears to be a single tuple instead of a list with 4 values. Try changing

```
cur.execute(
    " INSERT INTO MONTHLY_BUDGET VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", <--- Not sure!!!
    [(sheet.cell_value(rows,cols))])
```

to

```
cur.execute(
    " INSERT INTO MONTHLY_BUDGET VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", <--- Not sure!!!
    (sheet.cell_value(rows,cols)))
```

... or maybe

```
cur.execute(
    " INSERT INTO MONTHLY_BUDGET VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", <--- Not sure!!!
    ((sheet.cell_value(rows,cols))))
```

NB: untested. I've always changed how the bind variables in your SQL are being called.

Comment: This works... but now I am getting some different error :             File "C:\Users\praveen\Desktop\ReadDat
    (sheet.cell_value(rows,cols)))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: I edited my post. I don't think you were using bind variables in your sql correctly.